# How to scroll to the place where I've just typed the command in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, scrolling

In the terminal sometimes I typed some command that produces a long output. After it finishes I want to scroll to the beginning of the output text to read it but that's very hard to find. I colored the prompt string but many people don't and it's even harder to find the exact place in those cases.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS, the default Terminal has so called "marks" (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal), as well as iTerm2 has a nice shell integration feature, both allows you to jump to the previous command in the scrollback buffer.

For other terminal emulators, my best recommendation is to use the terminal emulator's search functionality for a string that's unique in your prompt (e.g. your username).

Comment: but is there a terminal with similar marks feature in Linux?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search through your command history in the Terminal.

When at the terminal, press **Ctrl-R** to begin a search, then you can type **nmap** and it will search back to the last command.

If you don't want the last command that contained the '**nmap**' word but want to go further then that, then you can hit **Ctrl-R** again. Practically you can do **Ctrl-R** as many times as you'd like.

You can also achieve the goal by **history** command. It will list all the command that typed from a while.

Thank you.

Comment: Well I was here much longer than you so you don't need to pray for accepting. And you're completely wrong, please read the question again. I need to **scroll** back to the position of the previous command, or the top of the output, not retype the command which I already used for a long time. And how is nmap relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

try: `command | less`. Where `command` is the command you are going to use.

Comment: What I want is a solution after the command has been typed. Sometimes one doesn't know that the output is that long, sometimes people forgot to redirect or pipe output